# Variable keeps its value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help once again. The problem is, when I call a function that should add to a variable, the variable stays at its original value.

Code:

```
import random

def christncombat(x,y,z):
    x += 1
    if x > 26:
        x = 1
        y += 1
    if y > 26:
        y = 1
        z += 1
    if z > 26:
        z = 1
        x = 1
        y = 1

encrypt = {65:90, 66:90, 67:72, 68:78, 69:77, 70:83, 71:87, 72:67, 73:73, 74:89, 75:84,
           76:81, 77:69, 78:68, 79:79, 80:66, 81:76, 82:82, 83:70, 84:75, 85:85, 86:86,
           87:71, 88:88, 89:74, 90:65}
encrypted = []

r1 = random.randint(1,26)
r2 = random.randint(1,26)
r3 = random.randint(1,26)
security = str(r1) + "a" + "-" + str(r2) + "b" + "-" + str(r3) + "c"

input_en = input("Zadejte text, ktery chcete zasifrovat (pouzivejte velka pismena): ")

for i in range(0,len(input_en)):
    coded = input_en[i]
    coded = ord(coded)
    coded = encrypt[coded]
    full = r1 + r2 + r3
    coded += full
    while(coded > 90):
    rekt = coded - 90
    coded = 65 + rekt
    christncombat(r1,r2,r3)
    full1 = r1 + r2 + r3
    coded += full1
    while(coded > 90):
        rekt = coded - 90
        coded = 65 + rekt
    done = chr(coded)
    encrypted.append(done)
print(encrypted)
print("Bezpecnostni kod je",security)
```

Although the issue is probably in this part:

```
def christncombat(x,y,z):
     x += 1
     if x > 26:
         x = 1
         y += 1
     if y > 26:
         y = 1
         z += 1
     if z > 26:
         z = 1
         x = 1
         y = 1
```

Comment: Stay do you mean "variable stays at its original value". What variable? With what value?

Comment: Can you describe you problem specifically? What variable, what value, what happened, what you expected to happen, etc.

Comment: Your `christncombat` function only modifies the local `x, y, z`, it has no effect on whatever you pass to it.

Comment: You aren't returning values from `christncombat`. You can't modify immutable types via arguments. Return back the new values.

Comment: In the complete code you can see that i call this function on variables "r1", "r2" and "r3". r1 being in position of x should change by 1, but it doesnt. When i try "def christncombat(r1,r2,r3): ... " basically nothing changes.

Comment: In order to modify `x`, `y`, or `z`, you'll need to store them in a mutable container, like a `list`, and then pass it or them to the `christncombat()` function.

Comment: @JáProstěJá You can't do this. As I said above, you need to return the values back. And I would advise against Martineau's suggestion. It may work, but it's a bad hack. Return a tuple holding the 3 values, and reassign them in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the modified values from the function, like this:

```
def christncombat(x,y,z):
    x += 1
    if x > 26:
        x = 1
        y += 1
    if y > 26:
        y = 1
        z += 1
    if z > 26:
        z = 1
        x = 1
        y = 1
    return x, y, z
```

Then in the calling code you can capture those returned values like this:

```
r1, r2, r3 = christncombat(r1, r2, r3)
```

Comment: I´ve read smth about this issue and I found a solution with "global" , however I can´t make it work. How do I implement it into the code? Trying your solution now.

Comment: @JáProstěJá Yes, it's _possible_ to modify global variables via the `global` directive, but that's generally not a good idea. It's easier to understand and modify code that doesn't use global variables to pass data around.

Comment: I´ve read that its a bad practise. Is that true that its just not good ? Is it bad practise just like the "goto" command ?

Comment: @JáProstěJá Yes, it's a bad practice. It can be handy in some situations, but there's almost always a better way that doesn't use `global`.

Comment: @JáProstěJá Globals are bad because if many functions are relying on a global value, it makes those functions harder to test, since you need to take into consideration the value of the global while testing. Whenever possible, the only data a function should use is what was passed as an argument. In reality, globals are necessary in some scenarios, but their use should be limited. You certainly should not get in a habit of using globals when they aren't necessary. That's the lazy way.

Comment: And this is the better answer. Tuples make far more sense in this context, and it doesn't use the unnecessary intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to return values from your function? You could put the values in a list and return the list:

```
 def christncombat(x,y,z):
      x += 1
      if x > 26:
         x = 1
         y += 1
      if y > 26:
          y = 1
          z += 1
      if z > 26:
          z = 1
          x = 1
          y = 1

      value_list = [x, y, z]
      return value_list
```

now, you can call the function in the main part of your code:

```
new_value_list = christncombat(r1,r2,r3)
```

now, in your new_value_list, you have r1, r2, and r3 all changed to what you want them to be. Now, you can access all the variables:

```
new_r1 = new_value_list[0]
new_r2 = new_value_list[1]
new_r3 = new_value_list[2]
```

Comment: I'd use destructuring in your last example instead of manually grabbing the elements. It would be significantly neater. Also, since it's a fixed sized collection, a tuple would be more appropriate than a list.

Comment: What's the point of these lists? Just return a tuple from the function, and use tuple assignment in the function call.